# $\langle T(v), w \rangle$ uniformly bounded in $v$ and $w$ implies that $T$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $V$ is a Hilbert space, $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map, and there is a constant $C$ such that

$$|\langle T(v), w \rangle| \leq C\|v\| \|w\|$$

for all $v \in V$ and $w \in W$.

Is $T$ necessarily bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=T(v)$ then
$$
\|T(v)\|^2= |\langle T(v), T(v)\rangle | \leq C\|v\| \|T(v)\|
$$
so for $\|v\|\leq 1$ we get
$$
\|T(v)\| \leq C
$$
hence $\|T\|_{op}\leq C$.

**Note:** The converse is also true by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
|\langle T(v), w\rangle | \leq \|T(v)\| \|w\| \leq \|T\|_{op}\|v\|\|w\|.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Take $w = T(v)$ where $T(v)\neq 0$ (otherwise the proposed relation holds trivially).

Then one concludes

\begin{align*}
\|T(v)\|^{2} = |\langle T(v), T(v)\rangle| \leq C\|v\|\|T(v)\| \Rightarrow \|T(v)\| \leq C\|v\|
\end{align*}

which implies that $T$ is bounded, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !